# @media rules for Monitor size which I use (max-width: 1920px) and my CSS are not working

Tags: html, css, attributes, tags, media-queries

Attribute cannot read on Monitor size @media (max-width: 1920px)

[image]

but when it goes to smaller sizes it is working

[image]

Comment: @media (max-width: 1920px){
.xl-four {
/* CSS here */
}
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are pointing two times the `max-width` attribute in your media query.

To be correct in this sense, you would need to target in between the media queries that you actually need. What you are imply in the screenshots you posted is that you first set a `max-width: 1280px` and then on top of it you put one more which is `max-width: 1920px`.

This is why it won't work.

It already takes the first limit which is 1280px.

What you need to do is:

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    #four.container.xl-four {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .xl-four {
         width: 100%;
         margin-right: 0px;
         margin-left: 55px;
         padding: 95px 0 75px 0;
    }
}
```

That will do the work. And for the next time, please post a reproducible example of your code so that all people can have a better understanding of the problem.

Thanks

Comment: is not an issue, the last media query will overwrite the first. and if you do it the way you do it you have to use `min-width: 1281px` otherwise at screensized of exactly 1280 bot media queries apply and the last one will overwrite the previos again (unless specificty weight comes into effect).